# document.referrer is empty in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, http-referer

I have a problem with document.referrer in IE.

I can see the referer in the request header but document.referrer always give me an empty string. It works in other browser.

I have a link pointing to another website (all of them are https), the other is in angular and in ngOnInit I call document.referrer, all browsers except IE11 works

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code with detailed steps to reproduce the issue? It can help us to test the issue and provide possible suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I just a have a link pointing to another website (all of them are https), the other is in angular and in ngOnInit I call document.referrer, all browsers except IE11 works

Comment: I try to test the issue on my side with the links and I also tested the issue with the Angular site using `OnInit`. Based on my test result `document.referrer` working fine. Here is my [test result](https://imgur.com/a/1GDibT6). So if possible, try to provide some code sample or more information will be helpful to narrow down the issue.